# Batch - get parameter that include special characters

Tags: batch-file, special-characters

I know there are many similar question but still not able to make it work.

I have a simple batch that accepts several parameters, one of them is a password which may include special characters.
The batch should run some .exe with the parameters that were sent to the batch.
Test.bat param1 param2 !@#$%^&*()_+

How should I handle the parameter with special characters ?
I tried using this code and also escaping the special characters with ^^ ^& etc.

```
  SET PASSWORD=%3

  SET "PASSWORD=%3"

  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  SET "PASSWORD=%3"
  echo !PASSWORD!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Important points:

- Doublequote the parameter `Arg1 Arg2 "!@#$%~^&*()_+"`
- Define the variable BEFORE enabling Delayed Expansion to preserve `!` characters and any character following / between `!` characters.
- Doublequote the string from the start of the variable name to the end of the variable content, and Use the `~` modifier to remove the surrounding doublequotes during assignment of the expanded argument variable.

```bat
@Echo off

 Set "Arg3=%~3"
 IF Defined Arg3 (
  Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  Echo(!Arg3!
 )

 Endlocal
```